# Copy Form Data to Another Element on Same Page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to create a preview panel for a data entry form that will add data to it in real time. with the script below, I can copy the data from one input to another input. What I'm trying to do though is have it copy from the text input to a p tag, and the code below won't do that.

```
function mirrorPre() {
    $('#post_title').bind('keypress keyup blur', function() {
        $('#preview_title').val($(this).val());
    });
}
```

and the HTML

```
<form method="post" name="eventForm" id="eventForm" class="eventForm">
    <input type="text" name="post_title" id="post_title" />
    <div id="preview">
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="preview-title" name="preview_title" id="preview_title" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I need the input form in the preview div to be a p tag.

Comment: You can't use `.val()` with a `<div>` or `<p>`. Use `.html()` or `.text()` instead

Comment: Great it works now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$('#preview_title').val($(this).val());
```

To this

```
$('#preview_title').text($(this).val());
```

only input elements have the `val` property. for other elements you can use `text` or `html`